# How can you count the number of permutations that have a given number of inversions?

Tags: combinatorics, permutations

Give a permutation $S_n$, we can count the number of [inversions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inversion_(discrete_mathematics)) efficiently in [$O(n \log n)$ time](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/counting-inversions/).  But given $n$ and a number of inversions $x$, is it possible to compute the number of permutations of length $n$ with $x$ inversions more quickly than brute force enumeration?

Comment: Do you know the generating function? It's very nice.

Comment: @QiaochuYuan No I don't!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $a(n,k)$ be the number of permutations of $\{1,2,\dots,n\}$ with exactly $k$ inversions. This satisfies the recurrence and base cases
\begin{align}
a(n,k) &= a(n-1,k)+a(n,k-1) - a(n-1,k-n)
\\
a(n,k) &= 0\text{ if $k<0$}
\\
a(1,0) &= 1,
\\
a(1,k) &= 0 \text{if $k\neq 0$}
\end{align}
These let you compute $a(n,k)$ in $O(nk)$ additions using dynamic programming. Since $k$ can be on the order of $n^2$, this is $O(n^3)$ at worst.

We can do a bit better with more sophisticated algorithms. Consider the polynomial
$$
(1+x)(1+x+x^2)(1+x+x^2+x^3)\cdots (1+x+\dots+x^{n-1})
$$
It can be shown that the coefficient of $x^k$ in this polynomial is exactly $a(n,k)$, so to compute $a(n,k)$, all we have to do is compute that polynomial. The most efficient way to this is as follows. There are $n-1$ factors. Group them into pairs, possibly with one leftover, and multiply each pair using Schönhage–Strassen multiplication, which multiplies two integer polynomials of degree $d$ in $O(d\log d\log\log d)$ arithmetic operations. You now have half as many factors; repeat until there is just one factor.

On the $j^{th}$ level of this process, you will be performing $\approx n\cdot 2^{-j}$ multiplications between polynomials of degree on the order of $n\cdot 2^j$, each multiplication taking roughly $O(n\cdot 2^j\log n\log \log n)$ operations. There are $\log_2 n$ levels, so the total amount of work is
$$
O(n^2(\log n)^2\log \log n)
$$

Comment: If you wanted to know the sum for j = 0 to k (that is total number of permutations with k inversions or fewer) is there anything cleverer you can do than compute each value separately?

Comment: " Since $k$ can be on the order of $n^2$"  Isn't the problem the size of $a(n, k)$ not the size of $k$.  $k$ will only ever have $O(\log n)$ bits.

Comment: I think there is a typo. It should be $a(n-1, k-n)$ .

Answer (score 1):

The Wikipedia article [Inversion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inversion_(discrete_mathematics)) has a link to [OEIS sequence A008302](https://oeis.org/A008302)

> T(n,k) = number of permutations of {1..n} with k inversions.

and the generating function of it for a fixed $\,n\,$ is

$$ A_n(q) := \sum_{k\ge 0} T(n,k)\,q^k = [n]!_q := \prod_{i=1}^k 
   \sum_{i=0}^{k-1} q^i. $$

No enumeration is needed to compute the coefficients 
$\,T(n,k)\,$ of polynomial $\,A_n(q).$

Comment: Thank you very much.